# Finding orthnormal wavefunctions to given wavefunctions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, wavefunction

Consider a particle in an infinite square well in one dimension. The potential inside the well is 0. The length of the potential well be L. Let the wavefunctions of the lowest three energy states be $\psi_1(x)$, $\psi_2(x)$, $\psi_3(x)$ which are also orthonormal to each other.
When measurement was done the particle was found in a state described by :

$\psi(x)$ =   $\alpha(\psi_1 + \psi_2 + \psi_3)$

Now my question is how to find other two wavefunctions that are orthonormal to each other and also to $\psi$ and expressed in terms of $\psi_1,\psi_2, \psi_3$.

So, I have tried to solve the question by first finding the value of $\alpha$ by normalization and is equal to $1/\sqrt3$.

Let the other two wavefunctions be $\lambda(x), k(x)$.

Assuming $\lambda(x) = a\psi_1 + b\psi_2 + c\psi_3 $
and $k(x) = A\psi_1 + B\psi_2 + C\psi_3 $.

According to question, $<\lambda|k>=0$

expanding term wise gives $a^*A + b^*B + c^*C=0 $

Similarly, $\alpha^*a+\alpha^*b + \alpha^*c=0 \\\alpha^*A + \alpha^*B + \alpha^*C=0$.

But now what? I am unable to solve further. Please help.

Comment: Well, you've found $\alpha$ (and it's real!), so that simplifies the equations a bit. Also, shouldn't $\lambda(x)$ and $k(x)$  be normalised too? And lastly, both $\lambda(x)$ and $k(x)$ should be orthogonal to $\psi(x)$ as well, shouldn't they? That should give you a fair number of equations.

Comment: And the system of equations **may** be under-determined which means there could be more solutions than you are looking for. You'll need to arbitrarily choose a coefficient.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:  View the wavefunctions as vectors and use the [Gram-Schmidt process.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process)